# Nested UpdatePanel: Why does ChildrenAsTriggers have no effect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, nested

Given a simple example with two nested Update-Panels. They are nested, and each one has a label which is filled with the current time in the code behind. I don't understand why the `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` - Property on the outer UpdatePanel has no effect? When I hit the 'Update Nested Panel' - button, the time in the parent UpdatePanel is not updated. But as far as I understand the property, it should be:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
    onasyncpostbackerror="ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:Button ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update Panel 1"
    style="margin-top: 15px" onclick="ButtonUpdate_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="ButtonUpdateNestedPanel" runat="server" Text="Update Nested Panel"
    style="margin-top: 15px" onclick="ButtonUpdateNestedPanel_Click" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonUpdate" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelNested" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonUpdateNestedPanel" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelNested" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thx for any tipps!
sl3dg3

p.s.: code behind:

```
protected void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabelNested.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
protected void ButtonUpdateNestedPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabelNested.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When the ChildrenAsTriggers property is set to true and any child control of the UpdatePanel control causes a postback. Child controls of nested UpdatePanel controls do not cause an update to the outer UpdatePanel control unless they are explicitly defined as triggers for the parent panel.
>   http://forums.asp.net/t/1422425.aspx/1

and this should be like...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonUpdate" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonUpdateNestedPanel" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
......   
......
```

Comment: hmm but then again I could leave `ChildrenAsTriggers` out - it would update either way... I simply can't make up the point of this property.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, in order to see the desired effect in action, you should actually add your buttons as children in the content template. The "ChildrenAsTriggers" property only applies to direct children of the "ContentTemplate" block.

Answer (score -1):

ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
Set the ChildrenAsTriggers property to true if you want postbacks from immediate child controls of the UpdatePanel control to cause an update of the panel's content. Child controls of nested UpdatePanel controls will not cause an update of the parent UpdatePanel control's content unless you call the Update method explicitly or you define the child controls as triggers.